# Avoid increment on duplicate entry

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a table with 3 columns namely number(auto increment), name(varchar), id(int). The problem is when i do `INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 (name, id) SELECT name, id FROM table2 WHERE id = someid` and ignored, the increment still goes up. Is there a way on how can i prevent increment when the entry is ignored (duplicated of course).

Comment: Why does the `number` column need to be contiguous?  Why is the increment a problem?

Comment: @dethtron5000 this `number` column is my queue reference and there should be no gaps.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL determines how many rows will be inserted by your statement. It then pre-allocates the auto-increment value in advance. This prevents multiple concurrent statements from interleaving auto-increment values.

**If once a number has been allocated, it cannot be used again.** That's the reason for the gaps between your auto_increment values.

You should **rewrite your query** so that it doesn't necessarily has to rely on auto_increment values. It's never a good idea to rely on auto_increment values.

Or do the following:

Since version 5.1 InnoDB has configurable Auto-Increment Locking.

```
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0  (“traditional” lock mode)
```

> This lock mode provides the same behavior as before
>   innodb_autoinc_lock_mode existed. For all “INSERT-like” statements, a
>   special table-level AUTO-INC lock is obtained and held to the end of
>   the statement. This assures that the auto-increment values assigned by
>   any given statement are consecutive.

[**Configurable InnoDB Auto-Increment Locking**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-configurable)

The innodb_autoinc_lock_mode cannot be changed while MySQL is running.

You'll either have to set it as server startup option

```
--innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0
```

or in the configuration file (my.ini)

```
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0
```

[**InnoDB Startup Options and System Variables**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html)

Comment: i have trouble understanding options file. i have set the `autoinc_lock_mode` to 0 using workbench but i cannot find my.ini in the directory of MySql server...

Comment: @carlot0820 - it's mysql/bin/my.ini

Comment: @carlot0820 - And don't forget to restart the server!

Comment: i have added the `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0` but it seem not to work. It still increments on duplicated entries.

Comment: @carlot0820 - Where did you place the option in your my.ini? To make that sure, it has to be placed in the server section [mysqld] (notice the trailing d) not in the client section [mysql]. After the server (not only client) restart, have you testet if the mode is set with `SELECT @@innodb_autoinc_lock_mode;` ?

Answer (score 0):

i have solved my problem by changing my table engine to `MyISAM` and setting `concurrent_insert` to `NEVER` on my options file.

hope it helps...